# Cannot deserialize Json into String array

Tags: java, json, string

I am trying to take an array of JSon objects and put it into a String array. I keep getting  `org.glassfish.json.JsonStringImpl cannot be cast to javax.json.JsonObject`
and don't know what to do about it.

Currently I have:

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
  String jsonStr = "";
  if(br != null){
      jsonStr = br.readLine();
  }

  // Create JsonReader object
  StringReader strReader = new StringReader(jsonStr);
  JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(strReader);

  // Get the singular JSON object (name:value pair) in this message.    
  JsonObject obj = reader.readObject();
  // From the object get the array named "inList"
  JsonArray inArray = obj.getJsonArray("inList");

  String[] myArray = new String[inArray.size()];

  // Fills myArray with Json Objects converted to Strings
 for (int i = 0; i < inArray.size(); i++) {
     myArray[i] = inArray.get(i).toString();
  }
```

Example input Json is: { "inList" : [ "Bob", "boj", "obb", "job", "BOB", "foo" ] }

Comment: When you used the writeObject method, you input a JsonStringImpl, and you want to reader.readObject() into a JsonObject, they are different, you can't

Comment: @azro is there any solution to this? My goal is to hash them but my hash function will not work if they are not strings

Comment: I’m not the one who will help here, I just pointed out the reason why it’s not working, you need to use the same classes at input and output

Answer (score -2):

So it seems to me that you're not quite parsing the json correctly due to a mismatch. When it comes to parsing JSON in java, it is strongly recommended to use a library called [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).

I have provided the full solution below:

```
class ClassName {
    static Gson gson = new Gson();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonStr = " { \"inList\" : [ \"Bob\", \"boj\", \"obb\", \"job\", \"BOB\", \"foo\" ] }";

        String[] inList = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, Container.class).inList;

        for (String s : inList) System.out.println(s);
    }

    private class Container {
        String[] inList;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Bob
boj
obb
job
BOB
foo
```

You would still obtain the JSON string as you do (post an additional question if you have trouble with that), but you would just stick my code right underneath to successfully parse the JSON array.

It is also possible to obtain a List instead of an Array. You can do that by replacing the field in the container class with `List<String> inList;`, and by changing the line in main to:

`List<String> inList = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, Container.class).inList;`

An additional note about your code:
Your if statement `if (br != null)` is always true, since you initialized it right above. In addition, the following `jsonStr = br.readLine()` may throw an IOException. You can catch it like this:

```
 try {
      jsonStr = br.readLine();
 } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      //do whatever you want etc.
 }
```